# CUDA parallelizing a dependent 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda

I have a sample loop of following form. Notice that my `psi[i][j]` is dependent on `psi[i+1][j], psi[i-1][j], psi[i][j+1] and psi[i][j-1]` and I have to calculate `psi` for inner matrix only. Now I tried writing this in CUDA but the results are not same as sequential.

```
for(i=1;i<=leni-2;i++)
for(j=1;j<=lenj-2;j++){
    psi[i][j]=(omega[i][j]*(dx*dx)*(dy*dy)+(psi[i+1][j]+psi[i-1][j])*(dy*dy)+(psi[i][j+1]+psi[i][j-1])*(dx*dx) )/(2.0*(dx*dx)+2.0*(dy*dy));
}
```

Here's my CUDA format.

```
//KERNEL
__global__ void ComputePsi(double *psi, double *omega, int imax, int jmax)
{
int x = blockIdx.x;
int y = blockIdx.y;
int i = (jmax*x) + y;
double beta = 1;
double dx=(double)30/(imax-1);
double dy=(double)1/(jmax-1);

if((i)%jmax!=0 && (i+1)%jmax!=0 &&  i>=jmax && i<imax*jmax-jmax){
    psi[i]=(omega[i]*(dx*dx)*(dy*dy)+(psi[i+jmax]+psi[i-jmax])*(dy*dy)+(psi[i+1]+psi[i-1])*(dx*dx) )/(2.0*(dx*dx)+2.0*(dy*dy));
}
}


//Code
cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_psi, leni*lenj*sizeof(double));
cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_omega, leni*lenj*sizeof(double));
cudaMemcpy(dev_psi, psi, leni*lenj*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(dev_omega, omega, leni*lenj*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
dim3 grids(leni,lenj);
for(iterpsi=0;iterpsi<30;iterpsi++)         
    ComputePsi<<<grids,1>>>(dev_psi, dev_omega, leni, lenj);
```

Where `psi[leni][lenj] and omega[leni][lenj]` and double arrays.

The problem is sequential and CUDA codes are giving different results. Is there any modification needed in the code?

Comment: Irrelevant tip: I always declare input buffer as const pointer so I don't mess up.

Comment: Relevant tip: always separate input and output buffer, and NEVER write to global input buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in global memory and you are changing psi entries while other threads might need the old values. Just store the values of the new iteration in a separate variable. But keep in mind that you have to swap the variables after each iteration !!
A more sophisticated approach would be a solution working with shared memory and spatial domain assignment to the separate threads. Just google for CUDA tutorials for the solving of the heat/diffusion equation and you will get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Initially i was swapping variables after each iterations. But since my no of iterations is very large someone suggested swapping in cuda takes alot of time so i was searching for faster alternate approach. Your second solution seems interesting, i'll have a look on it. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to really swap. Just add a bool to your kernel and swap that bool on your host after every iteration. Then your Kernel must be implemented like 
`if(swap) { temp_psi = ... psi ...;} else {psi = ... temp_psi ...}`.

Comment: Helllo there, i tried searching for you first suggested approach of swapping but could find any solution worth to me. Can you suggest any suitable solution or link detailing solving the gauss-seidel using swapping variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=1;i<=leni-2;i++)
  for(j=1;j<=lenj-2;j++){
    psi[i][j]= ( omega[i][j]*(dx*dx)*(dy*dy) + 
                 (psi[i+1][j]+psi[i-1][j]) * (dy*dy) + 
                 (psi[i][j+1]+psi[i][j-1]) * (dx*dx) 
               )/(2.0*(dx*dx)+2.0*(dy*dy));
}
```

I think that this kernel is not correct sequentially either: the value of `psi[i][j]` depends on the order of the operations here - so you will be using not updated `psi[i+1][j]` and `psi[i][j+1]`, but `psi[i-1][j]` and `psi[i][j-1]` have been updated *in this sweep*.

Be sure that with CUDA the result will be different, where the order of the operations is different.

To enforce such an ordering, if possible at all, you would need to insert so many synchronizations that probably it's not worthwhile for CUDA. Is it really what you need to do?

Comment: Synchronization using this kernel would not help at all. As i suggested OP should use a swap variable. This kind of kernel function (the idea) is a typical example of a differential equation that has been solved using CUDA by many many people (including me). Solving PDEs/ODEs in parallel are part of the reason CUDA does exist at all ;-)

Comment: Yes, I think it's wrong sequentially either - but in case it's really what he intend to do... usually you need to write backward finite differences PDE kernel as `psi_new[i][j] = f(psi)` and then swap `psi` with `psi_new`. Both in parallel and sequentially. Let's see what the OP think about it.

Comment: That's exactly whats i was talking :-)